# Give feedback with MessageBox if nothing matches text file C#

Tags: c#, logic

I'm making a login system currently and I would like to present feedback when the username or the password are incorrect.

Here is the content of the text file from which I'm reading the details:

```
Ryan:password
Username:password
```

When I enter `Ryan` and `password`, it works fine and brings me to the next form.
However, when I enter `Username` and `password`, it comes up with the 'Username Incorrect' message box first, and then after I close out of that message box, it brings me to the next form.

I would like it to bring me directly to the next form without showing the Username Incorrect MessageBox first, even if I do enter the details on the second line. There would be more lines in the text file in the future.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] userdetails = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UserDetails.txt");
    foreach (string user in userdetails)
    {
        string[] splitDetails = user.Split(':');
        Login.username = splitDetails[0];
        Login.password = splitDetails[1];

        label1.Text = Login.username;
        label2.Text = Login.password;

        if ((txtUsername.Text == Login.username) && (txtPassword.Text == Login.password))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + Login.username);
            this.Hide();
            frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
            menu.Show();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((txtUsername.Text == Login.username) && (txtPassword.Text != Login.password))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password incorrect");
                break;
            }
            if(txtUsername.Text != Login.username)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username incorrect");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is incorrect.

Ask yourself, when should you stop going through your list of credentials?

Assuming a username is unique, I see only one situation that could break your loop, and that is "the username has been found".

As soon as you find the input username in your list, you know the loop has to break. You then only have to check whether the password is correct or not.

If the password is correct, you can open your new window and `return` your function, it has done its job.

And after the loop, you put your MessageBox, with a message depending on if the username has been found or not.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] userdetails = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UserDetails.txt");
    bool usernameFound = false;
    foreach (string user in userdetails)
    {
        string[] splitDetails = user.Split(':');
        Login.username = splitDetails[0];
        Login.password = splitDetails[1];

        label1.Text = Login.username;
        label2.Text = Login.password;

        if (txtUsername.Text == Login.username)
        {
            if (txtPassword.Text == Login.Password)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + Login.username);
                this.Hide();
                frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
                menu.Show();
                return; // we're done here, so return instead of break
            }
            usernameFound = true;
            break; // we're not gonna find this username again, so might as well quit the loop
        }
    }

    //we only get there if the credentials were incorrect
    //so we check if the username was found, if yes, the
    //password was incorrect, if not, the username was        
    string message = String.Empty;
    if (usernameFound)
        message = "Password";
    else
        message = "Username";
    message += " incorrect";
    MessageBox.Show(message);

    //or shorten the above 7 lines with a ternary operator
    //MessageBox.Show((usernameFound ? "Password" : "Username") + " incorrect");
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks. However, could you explain the line:  MessageBox.Show((usernameFound ? "Password" : "Username") + " incorrect"); to me?      Thanks!

Comment: It's a ternary operator, it allows you to write short condition checks. It writes like `condition to check ? result if true : result if false`. I edited the answer with the non-ternary equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In your senario if you had 100 users (user1..user100)
your code reads

```
for each line in file
  check if matches 
     if yes make new form 
     else complain it isnt a match
```

So for user100, 99 its not a match messages will appear one for each non match before it.

You would need to code it like this

```
isfound=false
 for each line in file
   check if match  
     if yes set isfound and break

if isfound 
   show form blah
else
   whine not found
```